# Saving vectorized images to a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have four images that I converted to a vector. I'm trying to save those vectors in a `numpy` array to have a similar structure to the following matrix:

```
np.array([[0,0,1],
         [0,1,1],
         [1,0,1],
         [1,1,1]])
```

This is what I did:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

image1 = Image.open('cat0.jpg').convert('L')
image_array1 = arr = np.array(image1)
image_array_to_vector1 = image_array1.ravel()

image2 = Image.open('cat1.jpg').convert('L')
image_array2 = arr = np.array(image2)
image_array_to_vector2 = image_array2.ravel()

image3 = Image.open('cat2.jpg').convert('L')
image_array3 = arr = np.array(image3)
image_array_to_vector3 = image_array3.ravel()

image4 = Image.open('dog1.jpg').convert('L')
image_array4 = arr = np.array(image4)
image_array_to_vector4 = image_array4.ravel()

X = np.array(image_array_to_vector1,image_array_to_vector2,image_array_to_vector3,image_array_to_vector4)
```

I'm however getting the following error:

```
X = np.array(image_array_to_vector1,image_array_to_vector2,image_array_to_vector3,image_array_to_vector4)
ValueError: only 2 non-keyword arguments accepted
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you are looking for [`numpy.vstack()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe to pass it a multidimension array you would have to need to place the arguments to the array method in array notation:

```
X = np.array([image_array_to_vector1,image_array_to_vector2,image_array_to_vector3,image_array_to_vector4])
```